# Store my criteria/rules in one place?

Tags: windows, email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, microsoft-outlook-2013

I created a conditional formatting rule to highlight certain emails (sent directly to me, doesn't contain some text in subject, does contain other text in subject, etc).

This works great, but now I want to create a search folder with the same criteria. Do I really have to go through the SAME dialogue boxes and do this all over again? That seems really dumb. How can I access that same criteria I set for my conditional formatting rule and create a search folder out of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to copy your criteria to Search Folders other than using the manual way.

Answer (score 0):

You can export the rule, then re-import it.

- Under Rules and Alerts, click `Options`
- Click `Export Rules` and select a destination for the `.rwz`, click `Save`
- Click `Import Rules` and select the `.rwz` file

Then edit the parameters of the duplicate rule.